# Verifying Django Password in Ruby on Rails gives non-matching password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, encryption

I am rewriting a Django app in Ruby on Rails and want to preserve the old passwords for users.

Django uses PBKDF2SHA1 as the encryption mechanism. So one encrypted password I have is this

```
pbkdf2_sha256$10000$YsnGfP4rZ1IZ$Tpf4922MoNEjuJQA9EG2Elptyt3dMAyzBPUgmunFOW4=
```

the original password is `2bulls`

In Ruby, I use PBKDF256 gem and base64 for the checking.

```
Base64.encode64 PBKDF256.dk("2bulls", "YsnGfP4rZ1IZ", 10000, 32)
```

I am expecting

```
Tpf4922MoNEjuJQA9EG2Elptyt3dMAyzBPUgmunFOW4=
```

However, I got

```
YEfK6oUGFHdaKZMDXC0Dz8TpwsJlKfqC5vjCxjo+ldU=
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE

Found code in django source if it makes more sense to you.

```
class PBKDF2PasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
    """
    Secure password hashing using the PBKDF2 algorithm (recommended)

    Configured to use PBKDF2 + HMAC + SHA256 with 10000 iterations.
    The result is a 64 byte binary string.  Iterations may be changed
    safely but you must rename the algorithm if you change SHA256.
    """
    algorithm = "pbkdf2_sha256"
    iterations = 10000
    digest = hashlib.sha256

    def encode(self, password, salt, iterations=None):
        assert password
        assert salt and '$' not in salt
        if not iterations:
            iterations = self.iterations
        hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, digest=self.digest)
        hash = base64.b64encode(hash).decode('ascii').strip()
        return "%s$%d$%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, iterations, salt, hash)

    def verify(self, password, encoded):
        algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
        assert algorithm == self.algorithm
        encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt, int(iterations))
        return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)

    def safe_summary(self, encoded):
        algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)
        assert algorithm == self.algorithm
        return SortedDict([
            (_('algorithm'), algorithm),
            (_('iterations'), iterations),
            (_('salt'), mask_hash(salt)),
            (_('hash'), mask_hash(hash)),
        ])
```

CONCLUSION:

It turns out that only the account with 2bulls being the password has this problem. The other accounts are fine. When I know the exact reason for inconsistent password for 2bulls, I will post here.

Comment: I assume the salt you're using came from the Django installation, and the iteration number is from there as well (`$10000$` in that first password?). The length matches. Any chance the issue is with the Base64 encoding?

Comment: yes. second argument is the salt. third argument is the number of iterations, last argument is key length. I am digging into django source code to investigate now.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I see now where you derived all the arguments. So first it gets a sha256 digest, then runs it through pbkdf2, then base64 encodes. Is that what the Ruby gem is doing? (I'll look too.) Also, can we verify that Python's sha256 hash generates the same output as Ruby's on the same string? That seems like a least common denominator.

Comment: aaaah, never mind, the gem isn't using Ruby's sha256, it's using its own C-based version. I am way over my head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you hash that password `2bulls` using the following script (same logic that Django uses to hash passwords) this is what you get (ran this on Django's shell):

```
>>> import base64, hashlib
>>> hash = pbkdf2("2bulls","YsnGfP4rZ1IZ", 10000, 32, hashlib.sha256)
>>> hash.encode('base64').strip()
'YEfK6oUGFHdaKZMDXC0Dz8TpwsJlKfqC5vjCxjo+ldU='
```

Notice how I'm using the same parameters that you are using in Ruby:

```
password = "2bulls"
salt = "YsnGfP4rZ1IZ"
iterations = 10000
dklen = 32
digest = hashlib.sha256
```

Are you sure your expected hash corresponds to password `2bulls`?

Answer (score 0):

I've just released a gem for this purpose. I too, get the same result as @Daniel Aronne :

```
require 'pbkdf2_password_hasher'

puts Pbkdf2PasswordHasher::hash_password('2bulls','YsnGfP4rZ1IZ',10000,32)
#=> "YEfK6oUGFHdaKZMDXC0Dz8TpwsJlKfqC5vjCxjo+ldU="
```